# VMWare Workstation CPU Usage hitting 100%

Tags: vmware-workstation

Is there anything I can do to prevent my Vmware Workstation CPU usage from hitting 100%? I only have one program running on it and it's continuously hitting 100% CPU usage, yet it works outside of the workstation without any issues.

Comment: How many cores does the virtual machine been configured to use

Comment: When I first login to the VM, it says I have 1 core. However my PC is actually using 2 I think. Checking my computer shows I am using "AMD Anlon(tm) Dual Core Processor 5050e 2.6 GHz". Do I just need to increase the cores to 2 on my VM?

Comment: You think I need certainty to comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open up the Task Manager and remove one core from the Processor Affinity screen.

It will effectively prevent that application from using all of your CPU cores

[image: Task Manager]

[image: Set Affinity]

If it works outside of the workstation without issues then is that second computer more powerful? Does your workstation have other things running? How have you confirmed that this software is in fact causing the issue? Is the workstation infected with a virus?

If you are really feeling brave then you can look into setting priorities and stuff but that could screw things up on your system.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot for all the great information! I think we're on the right track here. Like I just commented on the original post, my VM is showing I am only using 1 core. So I'm assuming the program is already just using the 1 core. Do you think the whole issue here is that the program needs to be using 2 cores like my PC is using? It's not a second computer I'm using. I'm running 1 PC (where the program works fine), but on that same PC I'm also running VM and the program doesn't work fine there. Do you think I need to change my VM to use 2 cores instead? Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Also to answer your other questions. I don't think I have a virus or anything like that. I just installed VMware and started using it. I know it's this particular software because a bunch of other programs run on the VM without any issues, but then once I open this software, it starts intermittently jumping to 100 CPU usage.

Comment: You can certainly try giving your workstation another core but that could have a severely negative impact on your physical machine because now your machine has to compete for resources that your VM is requesting. So if your VM gets pegged to 100% on both cores then your physical machine is at 100% as well. The CPU you mentioned in your comment is very weak by today's standards so I am interested to know what application you are trying to run anyways? To change your core usage then shut down your VM, right-click on it from your menu and access the `Virtual Machine Settings -> Processors tab`

Comment: I have observed that I seem to be waiting more for VMware Workstation with the newer versions. For example, just sat here with v12 totally saturating my host PC. Been at 100% for over 10 minutes with just two VMs running - one of them should be pretty idle. Ahh there you go - as typing the log jam cleared and CPU dropped down to normal